# Excel / VBA - Multiple Rows to One Based on Positioning - How do i check cell value then save the value in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel

My excel sheet has value of data in right cell so its like

```
+---+--------+---------------------+
|   |   A    |          B          |
+---+--------+---------------------+
| 1 | School | newyork high school |
| 2 | Head   | Mr john             |
| 3 | phone  | 0191919             |
| 4 | email  | john@school.com     |
+---+--------+---------------------+
```

School name in single cell then others data are next to the cell. I want to arrange them vertically  like

```
+---+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|   |          A          |    B    |    C    |        D        |
+---+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+
| 1 | School              | Head    | Phone   | Email           |
| 2 | newyork high school | Mr john | 0191919 | john@school.com |
+---+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

I am trying to get the  value of next cell in following way.

```vb
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("a1:a40")
    If cell.Value = school Then
        Range("E3").Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value   
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish, however, this should get you started:

```vb
Sub transposeCellData()
    Dim Rng As Excel.Range
    Dim cll As Excel.Range
    Dim schoolName As String
    Dim schoolHead As String
    Dim schoolAdd As String
    Dim schoolWeb As String
    Dim schoolPhone As String
    Dim schoolFax As String
    Dim outRow As Currency
    outRow = 2
    Set Rng = Range("A1:A40")
    For Each cll In Rng
        If ucase(trim(cll.Value)) = "HEAD:" Then
            schoolName = cll.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            schoolHead = cll.Offset(0, 1).Value
            schoolAdd = cll.Offset(1, 1).Value
            schoolWeb = cll.Offset(2, 1).Value
            schoolPhone = cll.Offset(1, 3).Value
            schoolFax = cll.Offset(2, 3).Value
            Range("I" & outRow).Value = schoolName
            Range("J" & outRow).Value = schoolHead
            Range("K" & outRow).Value = schoolAdd
            Range("L" & outRow).Value = schoolPhone
            Range("M" & outRow).Value = schoolFax
            Range("N" & outRow).Value = schoolWeb
            outRow = outRow + 1
        End If
    Next cll
End Sub
```

Let me know if that helps. +1

Comment: Hi its working Thankx except phone and fax i guess they are out of range so i need to set the range Range("A1:B40") right?

Comment: No.  Updated answer, had the offset() values set wrong for phone and fax.. Should now be capturing them fine..  Please accept if so.

Comment: Please retry the updated answer code..  Should be working now.

Comment: Working fine. Thanx . But i have no cell named as  'school' school's names are appeared up cell of head please see the file link. I think we can do it without IF ELSE now i need to get the school name from up cell of head

Comment: I am unable to download the file.  I have updated the answer code one more time to search for the "Head:" cell, and find all records (including the school name) based off of it's positioning rather than searching for "school"

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/4xt78bavn/  here is the screenshot . school name are appeared up cell of head

Comment: I am taking off for the day, hopefully someone else can step in for me if you need anything else.

Comment: Can i get your skype id? thanx :)